# How to know all _kanji_ with certain radical?

Tags: kanji

Is there any official resource listing all Japanese *kanji* with a given radical? For example I want to know all *kanji* with the radical 亻.

When I looked I found many sites, but each site has a different number of *kanji*. I can study from the site with the largest number but what if there are more *kanji* with this radical ? So I need an official resource.

And there is another big problem. For example, some sites say that the *kanji* 倍 contains 亻+ 立 + 口, and other sites say it contains this radical 亠. So an official resource can be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by 'official'? What would 'all Japanese _kanji_' include?

Comment: @MathieuBouville  i deleted "japanese kanji" term ... what I mean with "official" is a site with full information and resources about this topic (radicals).... For example i wanna know all  kanjis with this radical亻.. is there any site can give me the full list

Comment: 公益財団法人 日本漢字能力検定協会 is pretty official, ain't it? If you wanna get your hands dirty with printed material maybe try: https://www.amazon.com/Kanken-jiten-Noryoku-Kentei-Kyokai/dp/4890963057/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=kanji+kentei&qid=1550948992&s=gateway&sr=8-6

Comment: You can check Unicode blocks for all CJK characters with the radical   亻, but it's really hard to tell whether they are "Japanese Kanji" or not without a clear criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know all kanji with the radical 亻

I'm not sure that you actually want to do this.

---

Firstly, I think it's helpful to clarify what a radical actually is.

[image]

A *radical* (部首) is a *section* (部) *header* (首) of a *dictionary*. It is *exactly analogous* to the *first letter* of an English word - they are both just *dictionary indexing tools*.

Wanting to know all *kanji* with the radical「亻」is like wanting to know all English words starting with the letter「Ａ」. I'm sure that you'll agree that this is not the most helpful way of learning English (or *kanji*).

---

Perhaps, instead, you meant that you want to know all *kanji* containing「亻」as a character component. Given the long history of *kanji* and how they have changed over the years, there is not actually a reference (as of early 2019) that tells you **all** the *kanji* containing some component X. Two major reasons are:

1. *Kanji* components change shape depending on where they are found in the character. The stand-alone shape of「人」is a side-view of a *person*.

   <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
   [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
   [image]
   [鐵](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)191.1
   [合集10869](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=10869&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
   [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
   [image]
   [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・2</kbd>
   　<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
   簡
   [image]
   [睡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)・[日乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)17</kbd>
   　<kbd>今
   [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
   [image]</kbd>

   - 「人」becomes「亻」generally when the next stroke after「人・亻」is written towards the right side.

     > <kbd>商
     > 甲
     > [image]
     > 簠地57
     > [合集6330](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6330&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
     > [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
     > [image]
     > 大盂鼎
     > [集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>楚
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・197</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>今
     > 楷
     > [image]</kbd>
     >
     > 「保」was originally a picture of a *person*「人・亻」carrying a *child*「子」on their back, indicating the meaning *carry, protect*.
   - 「人」becomes「儿」when it is found at the bottom of characters.

     > <kbd>商
     > 甲
     > [image]
     > [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)3798
     > [合集17644](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=17644&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>楚
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [包2](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・217</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>秦
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [日甲125背](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)</kbd>
     > 　
     > <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
     > [image]
     > [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
     > [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
     > [image]
     > 北海相景君</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>今
     > 楷
     > [image]</kbd>
     >
     > 「先」was originally a combination of a *foot going away from a place*「之」and a *person*「人・儿」, indicating the original meaning *to go forward > first, before*.
   - 「人」may also be mirror-reflected, rotated, and there are plenty of exceptions...

     > <kbd>商
     > 甲
     > [image]
     > [菁](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.1
     > [合集6057](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6057&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [睡・法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)174</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>今
     > 楷
     > [image]</kbd>
     >
     > 「北」originally depicted two people *back-to-back*. This meaning is now written as「背」, formed by adding an additional semantic「肉・⺼」.
2. *Kanji* components may have fused with other components, so in some characters you can't actually tell them apart in the modern script anymore.

   - > <kbd>商
     > 甲
     > [image]
     > [粹](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)853
     > [合集28287](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28287&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
     > 金
     > [image]
     > 鄀公平侯鼎
     > [集成2772](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2772&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [睡・編](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)7</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>東漢
     > 隸
     > [image]
     > 夏承碑</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>東漢
     > 隸
     > [image]
     > 華山廟碑</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>今
     > 楷
     > [image]</kbd>
     >
     > 「[年]{ねん}」([*Baxter-Sagart*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)) [OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Chinese):**/*C.nˤi[ŋ]/**; *year*) was originally a combination of semantic「禾」(*grain, crops*) and simultaneously semantic and phonetic「[人]{にん}・亻」(**/*ni[ŋ]/**; *person*), depicting a *person* carrying *harvested grains* on their back and indicating the meaning *(yearly) harvest*.「人・亻」was later modified into「[千]{せん}」(**/*s.n̥ˤi[ŋ]/**) through the addition of a horizontal mark but remaining as a phonetic, then the separate components completely joined together.
   - > <kbd>商
     > 甲
     > [image]
     > [明](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2065
     > [合集17950](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=17950&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
     > 金
     > [image]
     > 邢侯簋
     > [集成4241](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4241&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>秦
     > 簡
     > [image]
     > [睡・法](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)64</kbd>
     > 　<kbd>今
     > 楷
     > [image]</kbd>
     >
     > 「[重]{ちょう}」(**/*N-toŋʔ-s/**; *heavy*) was originally a combination of semantic「人・亻」and simultaneously semantic and phonetic「[東]{とう}」(**/*tˤoŋ/**; *picture of a bag*), depicting a *person* carrying a *heavy bag*, indicating the meaning *heavy*.「土」was added later and the three components「人・亻」,「東」, and「土」were fused very early onwards.

Comment: Hi droooze , I meant somthing like this https://www.nihongo-pro.com/kanji-pal/list/radical/9/strokes   is there a bigger list ?

Comment: @user32763 that list is incredibly misleading. A large number of characters on that list do not contain「人」.

Comment: yes I know that the most of them use 亻 ..  I meant the genral idea of this list of kanjis that use certain radical ... is there a site which bigger and better than this?

Comment: There are plenty, if you don't restrict to Kanji (which needs a clear definition) but are open to lists containing CJK ideographs.